# Tensorflow cannot fit a list of images

Tags: python, image, tensorflow

I have a spreadsheet with data. Each row is associated with a locally stored image. Together, they make up my training sets.

The images repeat; That is, each row does not have its own unique image. So, I have been trying to train the model by splitting up the dataset by image (that makes a lot of the other coding easier as well). I have been trying a lot of different things, and nothing seems to work. Currently, I am stuck here:

```
img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image) # PIL img to tensor
images = [img]*len(training.values)
model.fit(
{"images": images, "data": training.values},
labels.values,
epochs=5)
```

This gives me the error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

I have no idea how to make progress. None of the image related tutorials I find on Tensorflow are importing/processing images individually, so they tell me nothing about what the dataset is supposed to look like.

The model seems to be right since tf.keras.utils.plot_model shows me the correct plot. Also, traceback shows that the problem starts at model.fit.

Comment: Have you tried to pass "img" list to  tf.convert_to_tensor()?

Comment: @GiorgosLivanos No, but I figured it out; Turning the list of images into an array of images seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing a bit more around with the code, turning the list of images into an array with Numpy solved the problem:

```
images = np.array([img]*len(training.values))
```